# Annotation with NSManagedObject

Tags: objective-c, core-data, mapkit

I'm relatively new to objective-C and iOS, so I ran into a problem using an `NSManagedObject` subclass as a `MKAnnotation`. I do a fetch request to get all 'Places' (the `NSManagedObject` subclass and `MKAnnotation`), so I can populate the map.

All fine getting fetching them on `viewDidLoad` on the `MapController`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    DatabaseHelper *db = [DatabaseHelper newDatabaseHelper]; // does all the fetch requests ahead...

    NSArray *places = [[db getPlacesForDeck:@"PlacesDeck"] allObjects];
    /*
    [places enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(Place *place, NSUInteger i, BOOL *stop) {
        NSLog(@"Place Number: %d", i);
        NSLog(@"Place : %@", place.name);
        NSLog(@"Place latitude: %@", place.latitude);      ALL FINE HERE
        NSLog(@"Place longitude: %@", place.longitude);
    }];
    */
    self.annotations = places;
    [self.mapView addAnnotations:places];
}
```

NSLog reports fine, however as the maps gets drawn the **annotations title, and coordinates default to null, and (0,0).**

```
- (NSString *) title{
    return self.name; //name is an attribute from NSManagedObject subclass.
}

- (CLLocationCoordinate2D) coordinate{

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord;

    coord.latitude = [self.latitude doubleValue];   // Longitude and latitude
    coord.longitude = [self.longitude doubleValue]; // also dynamic attributes.
    return coord;
}
```

My guess was that as I pass the 'places' array I somehow dereference each place. However I read somewhere `NSArray` strongly references those objects, so I'm not quite sure how am I "loosing" the data. Any tips on what's happening? Or am I taking the wrong approach?

Comment: Dumb me, solved it. It seems that since I wasn't keeping the DatabaseHelper referenced, which had the NSManagedObjectContext instance, and thus the NSManagedObject had no context and was being lost.

Just needed to create an ivar with a reference to DatabaseHelper to keep it alive.

Answer (score 0):

the coordinate accessor is simpler like this:

```
- (CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate{
    return CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(self.latitude, self.longitude);
}
```